# Playframework Default value for just one form field

Tags: scala, playframework

Having this form:

```
case class DatabaseServerForAdd(name: String, address: String, port: Int, autoCheck: Boolean, serverIdentityId: Int)

object DatabaseServerForAdd {
  val databaseServerForAddForm = Form(
    mapping(
      "name" -> nonEmptyText(minLength = 2),
      "address" -> nonEmptyText,
      "port" -> number,
      "autoCheck" -> boolean,
      "serverIdentityId" -> number
    )(DatabaseServerForAdd.apply)(DatabaseServerForAdd.unapply)
  )
}
```

I just want the field `autoCheck` to have a default value of `true`, but I can not find a way.

The only way to handle defaults is using the `fill` method, but i have to provide a full object, and I do not want a default value in the other fields, I know, the strings could be empty, but i do not want a 0 in `port` and `serverIdentityId`.

Also, the `default` used in the docs, only works when the form is submitted, not when is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, seems the response is, sadly, there is no way, you can use the `fill` method like i said before, but with a full object.

The recomended thing to do, seems to be creating a custom object, where you can safely put all the non required fields as Option, so in the fill only the propierty that you want will be readed.

All the option fields that are none, will be set as an empty field (instead a 0 for an Int, for example).

**Edit**

Playframework 2.6 has default in forms https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaForms#default-values